# Decoding Local JSON File in Swift

Tags: swift

***As a result, it was annoying xcode bug. No error on another project, however accepted answer works for this problem.***

My error in `Data(contentsOf: url)`

```
Argument type 'URL' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'
```

**Local json file (countries with iso2 code)**

```
[{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
{"name": "land Islands", "code": "AX"},
{"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}]
```

**Model Struct**

```
struct CountryModel : Codable, Identifiable {

var id = UUID()
var name: String
var code: String}
```

**My way of decoding try**

```
 guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
        fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in the bundle.")
    }
    
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
        fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from the bundle.")
    }
    
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode([CountryModel].self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode.")
    }
```

I checked many resources, but the way of decoding may changed.

Comment: That error looks unrelated to the posted code. There seems to be important parts of the code missing, like what is `self` here and how is the `url(forResource:withExtension:)` function declared

Comment: Also, the json doesn't contain an `id` key so either add an `CodingKey` enum or make `id` into a computed variable on name or code

Comment: Do you have a custom object called `Data`? If yes rename it, it seems to interfere with Foundation `Data`.

Comment: I added coding keys for json file that doesn't have id and used this code inside `extension Bundle`, didn't help. I also make sure that there is no other `Data` object. As I am typing, I auto select `Data(contentsOf: url)` but however it still gives same error.

Comment: I still don't see how the error can originate from the posted code unless you have overridden some type or function from Foundation. Have you debugged this or used print statements to determine exactly which row it is that throws the error? That being said I alos think you should replace all those `try?` with a proper `try` within a `do/catch` so that you can print any error you might get .

Comment: Thanks all for your efforts. Exact code builded without any error in another Xcode project. Even though I cleared caches many times, it was a bug or something I couldn't also understand.

Comment: Then what was the question really? Maybe delete the whole question rather than accepting a random answer? (That actually looks worse than the code you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. Here is a toy demo of what I think you want. I placed a file named "Countries.json" in the Xcode project bundle.

```
    
@main
struct CountryApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            DemoView()
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var countries = Countries()
    @State private var selection = UUID()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, Countries!")
            List(countries.countries,  selection: $selection) { member in
                HStack {
                    Text(member.name)
                    Text(member.code)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

typealias CountryList = [CountryModel]

struct CountryModel : Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var code: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name
        case code
    }
}
    
struct Countries {
    var countries = CountryList()
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    init() {
        guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Countries", ofType: "json") else {
            print("Error getting filepath")
            return
        }
        do {
            let json = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath).data(using: .utf8)!
            countries = try decoder.decode(CountryList.self, from: json)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        print("Countries \(countries.count)")
    }
}
```

[image]